# Show Git conflicts in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ as an IDE and the terminal on Mac to do Github commands. I did a `git rebase -i origin/main` and there were some conflicts and an error saying:

```
error: could not apply 7d4bdfs7...
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

How can I display those conflicts in IntelliJ so that I can merge them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [IntelliJ Resolve conflicts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-conflicts.html#distributed-version-control-systems), you should have:

> If you click Close in this dialog, or call a Git operation that leads to a merge conflict from command line, a **Merge Conflicts** node will appear in the **Local Changes** view with a link to resolve them:
>
> [image: https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2021.2/git_merge_conflicts_node.png]

From there, clicking on one of those entries give you the window to resolve the merge conflict:

[image: https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2021.2/conflict_resolution_tool_legend.png]

From [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238894/discussion-between-vonc-and-inconnu), the OP confirms:

> It took some time for IntelliJ to show the merge conflicts.
> I didn't wait long enough the last time, that's why it was empty.

Comment: I tried that and my Local Changes is empty for some reason.

Comment: @inconnu Maybe because IntelliJ does not look at the same local Git repository?

Comment: Do you know where I can check that?

Comment: @inconnu Check out how if your IDE has opened a Git repository: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html

Comment: I checked and I think IntelliJ looks at the same repository since the Git Log shows a correct log.

Comment: @inconnu What `git status` shows you, in the folder looked by IntelliJ?

Comment: It's showing the correct branch that I'm currently working on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238894/discussion-between-vonc-and-inconnu).

Answer (score 0):

You can install `git gui`. After that, to see changes or conflicts, just run command `git gui`, it will show all the changed/uncommited files in the GUI based view.

Comment: Intelij IDE's already come with pretty good git integration.